# Is hg clone --chunked a valid statement?

Tags: mercurial, clone, kiln

I have downloaded the required kiln extensions for `--chunked` to work.

`hg push --chuncked works but not hg clone --chunked`

I was just curious if the below statement is valid?

```
hg clone --chunked [Source URL] [Destination URL]
```